# What is the partial derivative of sklearn's SVM (Hinge) loss function with regards to the input?

Tags: keras, svm

Does sklearn have a method to get out the gradient of the loss function w.r.t the input for an SVM that you have trained? I am also using a Gaussian (rbf) kernel.